# Bootstrap - Vertical Align Input Field

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on an app that uses Bootstrap 3. In this app, I have a row defined like this:

```
<div class="row" style="background-color:navy; color:white;">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <h2>Welcome</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-addon">
            find:
          </div>
          <input type="search" class="form-control" id="queryField" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>                    
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Go</button>                    
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to make the search field and the `Go` button vertically aligned with the `Welcome` text. The `Welcome` text is kind of vertically aligned. I tried adding `vertical-align: middle`. That did not work. I was trying to avoid using padding. But if its required, its required. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

There is default margin, padding in all

tags, so put a class of

```
h2{ margin: 0;  padding: 0; }
```

and it is automatically come in same line